# Pierdo las horas en Select en Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Estoy utilizando PL/SQL para realizar consultas y hacer lógicas en la base de datos.

Para este desarrollo necesito obtener la fecha más vieja de la tabla.

Si hago una select a la tabla me saca: ( por ejemplo ) Sin PL/SQL desde la opción de sqlWindows

```
21/10/2012 10:10:20
```

Es decir, saca dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss

Después cuando hago mi código de PL/SQL para realizar las operaciones:

```
     fecha VARCHAR2(100) := null;
     -- fecha DATE := null
     -- INTENTADO DE LAS 2 MANERAS.

     BEGIN
      SELECT FEC_ALTA
      INTO fecha
      FROM articulo
      WHERE cod_art = '1a';
          
          ...
      EXCEPTION
```

El caso, es que da igual que utilice el into fecha como un varchar2 o como un date, porque pierde las hh:mm:ss.
En tiempo de depuración al inspeccionar la variable no tiene las hh:mm:ss y cuando el resultado lo devuelve al JAVA tampoco tiene hh:mm:ss ...

Es Oracle y se está utilizando el IDE PL/SQL DEVELOPER 11.0.6
Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debemos suponer que tu campo es datetime o timestamp. Como no pones en la pregunta la definición de la tabla, habrá que adivinar.

Para obtener los datos en el formato específico que desees, puedes usar `to_char` para obtener una cadena que exprese la fecha como lo dice la [documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions180.htm). Al hacer el select sin más, realmente le está aplicando una máscara por defecto que sólo trae la fecha.

Ejemplo:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(FEC_ALTA, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SSxFF') 
INTO fecha
FROM articulo
WHERE cod_art = '1a';
```

Y te dará una salida similar a `21-OCT-2012 10:10:20`

Comment: Gracias, con la máscara funciona !

Comment: “Siempre debes usar to_char()”, ¿Resolver “siempre” un problema de presentación en la capa intermedia, o peor aún, en la de persistencia?

Comment: @Sal Muy importante tu comentario. ¡Depende! Si voy a operar sobre el dato, me lo llevo como fecha y lo manipulo. Si lo voy a presentar sin pensar, me ahorro la complejidad y los bytes :) Edito mi respuesta para evitar esos absolutos

Answer (score 1):

Lo primero es que NUNCA debe manipular un dato de tipo DATE por medio de variables VARCHAR2.

Oracle siempre almacena un valor de tipo DATE en 7 bytes:
siglo
año
mes
dia
horas (de 0 a 23 horas)
minutos  (de 0 a 59)
segundos  (de 0 a 59)

Esto es totalmente independiente del país, el idioma, la zona horaria.

Lo que Ud. ve en pantalla es una conversión automática que realiza su herramienta IDE (por ejemplo SQL-Developer o con SQL-Plus) de acuerdo a la configuración de idioma-lenguaje que tenga por defecto, o a que aplicó explícitamente el comando

ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT

Si para la tabla **ARTICULO** la columna **FEC_ALTA** es de tipo DATE entonces sencillamente use lo siguiente para obtener la menor fecha:

```
Declare
  fecha date;
BEGIN
  SELECT MIN(FEC_ALTA)
  INTO fecha
  FROM articulo
  WHERE cod_art = '1a';
  --
  -- si lo va a "visualizar" Y no usa TO_CHAR entonces Oracle le aplica el formato default 
  -- según la configuración de idioma-región que tenga el IDE
  Dbms_Output.Put_Line('fecha='||fecha));
  --
  -- Si usa la función TO_CHAR usar el parámetro 2 con el formato que desee
  -- por ejemplo el formato ISO-8601 para evitar confusiones
  Dbms_Output.Put_Line('fecha='||to_char(fecha,'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'));
End;
```

No conozco Java, así que no sé si en ese lenguaje tenga al algún tipo de dato equivalente al DATE de Oracle.

Si definitivamente para Java hay que entregar un string entonces solo en la variable de salida con destino a Java use la función TO_CHAR explícitamente con el formato ISO-8601 **yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss** para convertir un valor tipo DATE a un valor tipo VARCHAR2, el cual le garantiza que los strings tenga la secuencia de año-mes-dia-horas-minutos-segundos y que si los ordena queden ordenados de manera natural.

Comment: El PO menciona que usa Java, de tal manera que el manejo de los NLS dependería de la arquitectura de la aplicación.